# How to upgrade to libglib2.0 v2.3.6?

Tags: apt

The latest upgrades to Cairo-Dock have broken it so I tried to do a fresh install. But when doing `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock` I get the following error:

```
cairo-dock-plug-ins : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

So I tried to upgrade `libglib` since the package site says that the latest version is `2.36`, but `apt-get` says that `2.32.3` is the latest.
I would like to avoid having to install from source since `libglib` is a core library and provide dependencies to a lot of other packages.  So how can I convince `apt-get` or the Software Center to install the real latest version?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you are mixing repositories or using a ppa. The [`cairo-dock-plug-ins`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/cairo-dock-plug-ins) package in precise depends of `libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0)` not 2.35.9 and you have installed already a supported version `2.32.3-0ubuntu1`. You should disable all repositories except Ubuntu's and install again.